# How to get sorted result based on residential address in oracle 10g?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle10g

I want to query the Oracle 10g database and get result on the basis of residential address in ascending or descending order. So the problem is building addresses are at time in the form of 110C or 200D, so according to sql "order by" asc or desc, I get the result as 200D before 20. 
for eg, if adresses are 10 110 112 200D 232 95 20 100A 1050 944

In ascending order it will result in:-

```
 10 100 100A 1050 110 112 20 200D 232 944 95
```

The problem is as the adresses have characters in it, i can't consider them to be as integers or number, they have to considered as String.

Comment: Why would 20 between 112 and 232?  Shouldn't 20 be sorted between 10 and 100?

Comment: This isn't a sql language solution, but may give you some ideas ... http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html

Comment: That's probably a typo, since OP described the problem well...

Comment: @Justin Cave : The data list shown (`112, 20, 200D`) is what the OP ***gets*** from a niaive alphanumeric sort.  What the OP ***wants*** is what you desribed (`20, 112, 200D`)

Comment: @Adrian - That's what I was thinking initially.  But 95, 110, and 112 are also out of order so I started to suspect there was more to the problem than I was seeing.

Comment: Funny that mentioning `REGEXP_SUBSTR` gets up voted but posting an **actual** answer using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` does not...

Comment: @Dems - Ah, OK.  I'm misreading the question then-- that looks to me like the desired result not the actual result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

> Warning! Potential non-working code ahead. I do not have an Oracle instance to test it against at the moment.

```
SELECT YourAddress
FROM YourTable
order by TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(AddressColumn, '^[0-9]+'));
```

`REGEXP_SUBSTR` will find the number's substring which is supposed to start the address, convert it to a real number and order by it.

Caveat: you will have to improve the query to handle cases where a number will not be present. However, this answer can get you very well started.

When in need to fine-tune the query, here are the resources you should use:

- http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html
- http://psoug.org/snippet/Regular-Expressions--Regexp-Cheat-Sheet_856.htm
- http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm

And, yes, `REGEXP_SUBSTR` is available in Oracle 10g.

Comment: Goes a bit wonky with "The 7 Dwarfs" as a name. But in the absence of the OP clarfiying the exactly characteristics of the strings, this certainly works :)

Comment: @Dems Agreed. Also, OP will have to most certainly tweak based on the data. But for addresses that necessarily **start** with a number, that will work.

Comment: @Adrian - Thanks adrian, your query string works fine for my need :)

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression based solutions are more elegant.  But assuming you want to first sort on the numeric component using a numeric sort and then sort on the character component using a character sort, you can also use the `TRANSLATE` function.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with x as (
  2    select '10' addr from dual union all
  3    select '100' from dual union all
  4    select '100A' from dual union all
  5    select '1050' from dual union all
  6    select '110' from dual union all
  7    select '200D' from dual union all
  8    select '20' from dual
  9  )
 10  select addr,
 11         to_number( translate( addr,
 12                               '1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
 13                               '1234567890' ) ) addr_num,
 14         translate( addr,
 15                    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890',
 16                    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') addr_str
 17    from x
 18   order by to_number( translate( addr,
 19                                  '1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
 20                                  '1234567890' ) ),
 21            translate( addr,
 22                       'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890',
 23*                      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
SQL> /

ADDR   ADDR_NUM ADDR_STR
---- ---------- ----------------
10           10
20           20
100A        100 A
100         100
110         110
200D        200 D
1050       1050

7 rows selected.
```

Comment: Goes a bit wonky with "The 7 Dwarfs" as a name.  But in the absence of the OP clarfiying the exactly characteristics of the strings, this certainly works :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to accomplish this is to parse the street numbers into numeric and non-numeric parts, and store them in separate columns so you can index (or order by) on the numeric part first (as a number) and then the non-numeric part.  It may be possible to write an expression that does this, but then you lose any indexing (if that's important).

In Oracle 11 there's a REGEXP_SUBSTR function that could be used to accomplish this, but I'm not sure it exists in Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with oracle but generally with SQL something like that could help:

```
ORDER BY CAST(house AS integer), house
```

So basically you order by integer part of the field first (CAST should disregard all trailing non numerical chars), and if they are the same it should compare them as a string so 100A would be before 100b

**Apparently this will not work in Oracle. See comments**

Comment: Out of interest, what happens with CAST in Oracle if you give it 'A1', '1B2', or 'A1B2'?

Comment: This will not work: casting a field containing non-numeric characters as an integer will result in an "Invalid Number" error in Oracle. Any DB that discards non-numeric trailing characters in the conversion is not compliant with the SQL-92 standard (where `cast` was introduced).

Answer (score 0):

You have two basic options that I am aware of:
1. Force the field to a consistent format
2. Separate the numeric and non-numeric portions out

For option one, you would change `'10'` to be `'00010-'`, and `'100A'` to be `'00100A'`, etc.  They will then naturally order themselves.

For option two, you would change `'10'` to be `(10,'')`, and `'100A'` to be `(100,'A')`, etc.  Then order by the two portions (numeric and non-numeric) separately.

Either way, you need to know (or tell us) a little bit more about the definitive characteristics of the data.  (Is the pattern always [numeric][alpha], is the [alpha] portion always 1 character long, Do you ever have building Names, etc, etc?)